# How can I add the item to cart page in react

Tags: reactjs, e-commerce

I am trying to add items to a cart page when a user clicks the `add to cart` button. I tried to create a function inside the Product page with props but I can't use it without rendering all divs from the Product component.

### Product page

```
import './Product.css';


export function Product(props){

  return (
      <>
        <div className="product-container">
            <div className="product-background">
                <img className='product-image' src={props.image}></img>
                <img className='product-image2' src={props.image2}></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='description-container'>
            <div className="product-description">
                    <div className='product-title'>{props.title}</div>
                    <div className='product-price'>{props.price}</div>
                    <div className='product-button'><button type="button" className="product-btn">ADD TO CART</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </> 
    )
}
```

This is where I want to add and render items, instead of the hardcoded 3 cards.

```
import './Cart.css'

import { Header } from './Header'
import { Card } from './Catalog'

import hoodie1 from './images/hoodie1.png'

function Price() {
  return (
    <div className='price-cont'>
      <div className='price-cointainer'>
            <div className='total'>TOTAL</div>
            <div className='price'>00,00 €</div>
            <div className='checkout'>CHECKOUT</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default function Cart(){
    return (
      <>
         <Header />
         <div className='cart-container'>
             <div className='item-container'>
               <Card image={hoodie1} title="Hoodie FEARLESS" price="89,90 €"/>
               <Card image={hoodie1} title="Hoodie FEARLESS" price="89,90 €"/>
               <Card image={hoodie1} title="Hoodie FEARLESS" price="89,90 €"/>
             </div>
         </div>
         <Price />
      </>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea you want to do is to create an array of the items you want to add to your cart. Once your cart receives that array, you will have to loop through it and display the content on the page.

---

Note this is somewhat pseudo code, but with it you should be able to get going in your own code.

```
import { useState } from 'react' 

const ProductPage = () => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
  
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Item id="1" onClick={() => setCart((prev) => [...prev, { id: 1 }])} />
        <Item id="2" onClick={() => setCart((prev) => [...prev, { id: 2 }])} />
        <Item id="3" onClick={() => setCart((prev) => [...prev, { id: 3 }])} />
      </div>
      <Cart cartItems={cart} />
    </>
  )
}

const Cart = ({ cartItems }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Items in your cart:</h1>
      <div>
        {cartItems.map((cartItem) => (
          <p>{cartItem.id}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```